# How could original astronomers have used the clouds to find distances?

Tags: the-moon

I was looking at a very bright moon tonight through light cloud cover and saw a halo of light far bigger than the moon imposed on the clouds. Almost in a conic shape by comparison. I was wondering if early astronomers could use this difference to calculate the distance of the moon given the height of the cloud and the dimensions of earth.

Comment: @pm2ring the 22 degrees wouldnt aid a calculation of distance?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if it concerns the 22 degree halo, it is a meteology question.  If it is not about this halo, it is unclear

Comment: @PM2Ring that's a valid answer to this question, more than just a comment.

Comment: Could be, because the question is based a misconception, but it's a *question* about (historical) astronomy, with a non-astronomic answer.

Comment: @JamesK at the time I didn't know it was meteorological in nature. I've cast the final VTC vote, and accepted the answer posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because the size of the halo is determined by the properties of ice crystals, the distance to the Moon is irrelevant. So you get a [22° halo](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/22%C2%B0_halo)
 with both the Sun & the Moon, even though the Sun's much further away.

Comment: I shall, also I'll VTC my own question. Didn't mean it as meteorological, mostly because I didn't know it was meteorological.